# env node no such file diercory for in OS X el capitan

Tags: node.js, macos, less, odoo, odoo-9

I'm facing a very strange problem that i couldn't solve till now

I'm trying to install odoo 9 in OSX El capitan 10.11.6 but i'm facing a problem

when I'm trying to install any database i got `couldn't execute lessc command`, i install node and npm using brew and run command `sudo npm install -g less` and `sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css`, less installed in directory `/Users/mostafa/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/` ,when i try lessc command in the terminal i go that it couldn't found so i did this comman `sudo ln -s /Users/mostafa/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /usr/local/bin/lessc` and this command `sudo ln -s /Users/mostafa/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /usr/bin/lessc` ,, and now i could write lessc in command and run it successfully , so i managed to create now odoo 9 database and i got another error which is very strange it's `env: node: No such file or directory` so i search online for fixes like :`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` and `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`
but still get the same error

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

could i get some help please ?

Comment: Please provide the whole exception stack trace of `env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: there is no stack only that !